# Hosting a java made webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, localhost, ngrok

So I have been working on a web service which communicates between the client and server. It fully works on my computer and am able to send requests from client to server while not in the same package. 
I am hosting my service like:

```
public class WebServiceServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bindingURI = "http://localhost:4040/absolute/uploadService";
        FileReceive service = new FileReceiveImpl();
        Endpoint.publish(bindingURI, service);
        System.out.println("Server started at: " + bindingURI);
    }
}
```

And my client connects to my service like:

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
factory.setServiceClass(FileReceive.class);
factory.setAddress
("http://localhost:4040/absolute/uploadService");
FileReceive client =(FileReceive) factory.create();
```

From this point I would like to make the web-service public(able to connect from outside of the local-host). I installed ruby and ruby gems only to find out the local-tunnel is no longer available. I have then moved to using ngrok which forwarded a URL for me, but I cannot get any post requests to go through to it(as if it was my web-service) only get methods as I type the URL into my web-browser. Is anyone aware of any easier to use hosting services so that someone (outside of local-host) can post a file to my web-service? Thanks.

Comment: You problem might not be related to Java. When connecting to the server, are you using his public IP? If so, is your port (4040) open on the router and/or firewall? The best way to know is using a network traffic analyzer like wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) to see if your client request is actually reaching your server.

Comment: @jumojer What I am trying to do is make my web service available so that someone outside of my local host can post files to it. Lets say for example I wanted my dad to have the ability to send files from his house to my house over different ISP's (different localhosts) How would this be done? Mine is originally set up for localhost users only who can access it on that port. Correct?

Comment: To reach your server, your father would have to connect to your IP adress. NOT localhost. You can check your ip here http://www.whatismyip.com/ and then the people that want to connect to your server will change "localhost" for your ip.